React Native Expo Application that check if a package name is installed on the device
I want to check if a package name is installed on my device through react native expo, there is a library called react-native-check-app-install which does this but it's not maintained now.
We do have package manager in native android that checks this. Either of the following-

Package that is maintained, that checks the package name installed or not.
Steps to add the native code to my expo app, I have created the native code but I don't know how to add it to my expo project.


react-native-launcher-kit does the job for you, it's specific to android but it's working.

You are lucky, I have just made an expo package recently which will do your work. It checks for installed apps in android as well as iOS
Try it, It will surely save your time
https://www.npmjs.com/package/expo-check-installed-apps
